# Pointer to array in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, c++14

This post is more of a type of confirmation post rather than a particular question.

I read up some answers on this site and other places to clear up my confusion regarding pointers of type, ex- int(*)[size] which are pointers to an array. From what I've understood, there are some basic differences which I concluded on - 1) pointer arithmetic, 2) dereferencing . I wrote up this code to differentiate between int* and int(*)[size].

```
int arr1[5] {} ;
int (*ptr1) [5] = &arr1 ;
(*ptr1)[3] = 40 ;
cout << ptr1 << endl ; 
cout << ptr1[3] << endl;
cout << ptr1 + 3 << endl ;


int arr2[5] {} ;
int* ptr2 = arr2 ;
ptr2[3] = 40 ;
cout << ptr2  << endl ;
cout << ptr2[3] <<endl ;
cout << ptr2 + 3 << endl ;
```

Output :
[image]

On observing the output of arithmetic on int(*)[size] its evident that when we add say i to it , it jumps over a block of 4*size*i memory whereas the int* jumps over a 4*i memory block. Also in int* the expression of the form ptr2[i] is equivalent to *(ptr2+i) but in pointers of type int(*)[size] this is not the case ptr1[i] is equivalent to (ptr1 + i) and to replicate the action of ptr2[i] we have to do (*ptr1)[i] in this case.

Are there anymore significant differences between the pointers of such type and which pointer amongst them should be preferred and why ?
Please correct my analysis if I have gone wrong somewhere .

Comment: Btw the first snippet with `ptr1[3]` has undefined behavior.

Comment: @JasonLiam Could you explain why?

Comment: Why still use pointers to a "C" style array when we have std::vector? To make an "array" of "arrays" use std::vector<std::vector<int>>  (or std::array). Those types will also help you avoid memory allocation mistakes.

Comment: @Dhrxv Because in `ptr1[3]` you're trying to access memory that is not meant to be accessed by you.

Comment: @PepijinKramer I am doing this for the sole purpose of understanding pointers. I have no desire to use this practically, although thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Dhrxv `ptr1 + 3` points to memory that is not meant to be accessed by you. So if we dereference `ptr1 + 3` we will get undefined behavior.

Comment: @Dhrxv I see, your analysis is fine for the most part except that the 1st snippet has UB as pointed out before.

Answer (score 1):

There are no differences between different kinds of pointers.

If `p` has the type `T*`, `p + k` is the address `k * sizeof(T)` away from `p`.

If `p` is the location of an object that is not an array element (as is the case when you acquire it with `&`), `p[3]` and `p+3` are both undefined.
(In this case, `p[0]` is the only well-defined indexing, and `p+0` and `p+1` are the only well-defined arithmetical expressions – but you're not allowed to dereference `p+1`.)

Your pointer-to-array code is more similar to this `int*` version:

```
int x = 0;
int* ptr2 = &x ;
ptr2[3] = 40 ;
cout << ptr2  << endl ;
cout << ptr2[3] <<endl ;
cout << ptr2 + 3 << endl ;
```

which you can probably see is Just Wrong.

Comment: Yes I realize that the memory is not meant to be accessed by me. I could however use this in a 2-d array to jump over from a row to the next row, so I just used this as an example to differentiate bw the two types . What would be the equivalent expression for this  (*ptr1)[3] in terms of pointer arithmetic and dereference operator like the equivalent of ptr2[3] is *(ptr+3)

Comment: @molbdnilo First you've said in your answer that *"p+3 are both undefined."*. Then you said, *"p+0 and p+1 are the only well-defined arithmetical expressions"*. This seems contradictory.

Comment: @Dhrxv There are no differences; if the equivalent of `p[3]` is `*(p+3)`, and `p` is `(*ptr1)`, the equivalent must be `*((*ptr1) + 3)`, but I do not understand why anyone would prefer unreadable pointer arithmetic to indexing.

Comment: Oh I see so is ptr1 basically a pointer to a pointer to an array then?

Comment: @Dhrxv No, it's a pointer to an array. `*ptr1` is an array - it's an `int[5]` - and like all arrays it can decay into a pointer to its first element. That is, `*ptr1 + 3` is equivalent to `&(*ptr1)[0] + 3`.

Answer (score 0):

> **Are there anymore significant differences** between the pointers of such type and which pointer amongst them should be preferred and why ?

Yes, the first snippet with `ptr1[3]` results in **undefined behavior** as you're trying to access memory(pointed by `ptr1 + 3`) that is not meant to be accessed by you.

Note that just the expression `ptr1 + 3` is well-defined but if we try to dereference this like `*(ptr1 + 3)` or `ptr1[3]` then we will have undefined behavior.

> Undefined behavior means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen(from C++ standard's perspective) *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely** on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

On the other hand, `ptr2[3]` is well-defined.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For more reading(technical definition of) on undefined behavior you can refer to [undefined behavior's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) which mentions that: *there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program.*</sup>

Comment: Yes I realize that the memory is not meant to be accessed by me. I could however use this in a 2-d array to jump over from a row to the next row, so I just used this as an example to differentiate bw the two types .

Comment: @ArminMontigny Happy diwali to you too. Yes, actually dereferencing the pointer is undefined behavior but the expression `ptr1 + 3` is well-defined. While `*(ptr1 + 3)` is undefined.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic is well defined only if the result is an element of the same array as the pointer, or one-past-the-end. You don't need to dereference for it to be undefined. (And dereferencing is not the same as accessing memory.)